# Admob Rewarded Video third party

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob, interstitial

I have been trying my best to get the Admob Rewarded Video to work/show in my app, but I just can't get it to work.
I have all the plugins installed correctly I believe.

This is my current code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;



public class AdManager2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    string adUnitId = "MY_UNIT_ID";
    RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideo = null;

    void Start()
    {
        rewardBasedVideo = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;
    }

    public void adButton()
    {
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        rewardBasedVideo.LoadAd(request, adUnitId);
        showAd();
    }

    public void showAd()
    {
        if (rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded())
        {
            rewardBasedVideo.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work for me, I click the button but nothing works. I have also tried multiple scripts from different people too, but not a single one of them work for me...

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this,
Thanks in advance,

-Lente

Comment: Have you setup third-party reward video provider on Admob Dashboard??

Comment: @HardikMaru I have set up an RewardedVideo Ad Unit and inserted the unit ID in the "AdUnitId" String. I don't know if this is what you mean?

Comment: I mean, for showing Reward Video, we must add 3rd party rewardvideo provider on Google Ads Dashboard.

And to add 3rd party reward video provider, you must first setup that 3rd party provider's app dashboard.

Comment: @HardikMaru Sorry I'm afraid I still don't really understand the "3rd party rewardvideo provider" thing where you are talking about, or where I can find this. 
It does say on the Admob page that my "Match Rate" is 100%, this is the percentage of ad requests that were filled with an ad. Since my banner ads (these do work) are shown using a test function, and not with a real adunit id, maybe the problem is that the RewardedVideo advertisement just doesn't show up?

PS; my RewardedVideo Ad DOES use a real admob unit Id.

Comment: @HardikMaru *Update* I have found a tab called "Mediation" where I can add third party Ad Networks. Is this what you mean, and if so, would it help to add some of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of March 2017 you no longer need to set up 3rd party mediation to use Admob rewarded video, since Admob have started serving their own reward ads. In fact if you are testing its better not to use 3rd party mediation at this stage because of the difficulty in generating test ads.

With 3rd party mediation you sign up to a 3rd party ad network, and you set a "test" flag of some sort in the 3rd party ad units on the 3rd party's site. You then link these units into your admob unit on the mediation tab and create an adrequest.

On March 16 2017 when I tested admob didn't serve rewarded videos to test ad requests contructed using builder.addTestDevice - sending back error code 0.

When admob weren't serving their own rewarded video ads this approach worked fine, but now that they are you will get back live admob ads along with test ads from your 3rd party provider(s). If you click on a live ad during testing you are breaking admob Ts and Cs.

(however in your case you aren't using a test adrequest anyway)

This [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/k-kVwVu2XBc/JC973phMBgAJ) provides ad units for testing for IOS and Android, and I'd recommend using these.

If you are developing on android the best next step would be look at logcat and look for error responses from /ads

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I'll look into this soon. If I have anymore questions I will let you know.